# WPF Bind TextBlock to Window's Title

Tags: wpf, vb.net, binding, title, textblock

I have a TextBlock on my main window. 
I would like to bind it's text to the window's title .. eg: myWindow.Title.

This has been bugging me all night, and I have Googled to death, any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the MVVM Pattern ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The simplest way is just to bind back to the parent window:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Title,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window}}"  />
```